# Can I restart mongodb server through mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, client-server

Can I restart a MongoDB server through the mongo CLI client?

Answer (score 4):

You can't stop and start (restart) it from the client. As i.kimiko already mentioned, you can shut it down on your client with `db.shutdownServer()` through a mongo shell [database methods documentation 3.6.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.shutdownServer/)
But then you'd still have to connect to the server and restart it from there with `sudo service mongodb start` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can shutdown server via client.

```
mongo --host "hostname where server or IP" --port "port of mondodb server" --username "username" --password "password"
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

[link to documentation about db.shutdownServer() mongodb 3.6.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.shutdownServer/)

After that you may up that server via other service\tool (from a host machine when a mongodb server installed), like cron for example or using systemd unit.

Comment: Ok, got it. Use: mongo --host <hostname> --port <port> --username <username> --password <password> -> use admin -> db.shutdownServer()