# Restart mongod process from pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am not sure if this should be posted as an issue on the MongoDB github or should be posted here, so please bare with me.

**What I want:** 
My first goal was to restart the monogd server using the Mongo Python API (pymongo).  I guess that is [theoretically impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257580/can-i-restart-mongodb-server-through-mongo-shell) since after a shutdown, the API loses any link to the main server and can't ask it to restart.
**So, I changed plans:** 
I just wanted to shutdown the server from my python code, pause the code (using `input('Press enter')`) allowing user to manually restart the mongod server and then press enter to continue the code execution after the user has restarted the server.

The way I "shutdown" the server from pymongo and wait for manual restart inside the code is as follows:

```
shell = MongoClient(uri)
shell['admin'].command('shutdown')
input("Press Enter  button after restart.")
```

Problem is: 
I keep getting an "AutoReconnect" error when doing this. Even after catching the error as follows:

```
    try:
        shell['admin'].command('shutdown')
    except Exception as e:
        if "closed" in str(e):
            print("[UPDATE] Server was successfully shutdown. Please restart it.")
            input("Press Enter  button after you restart it.")
        else:
            raise e
```

Even after that, multiple "AutoReconnect" errors are raised. Without affecting the functionality of the code this time, just printing to stderr.

So, my question(s) are:

- Is there a better way to restart the server from Pymongo? Possibly one that does not involve humnan intervention ?
- How can I turn off the autoreconnect errors thrown ? Could not find any updated method to do so.

Comment: What is the OS of the server running the Mongo daemon and have you considered executing shutdown/restart at the OS level?

Comment: Update to latest driver.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere OS is Windows 10. When you say "at OS level" you mean via a python library that has access to the command line? (os python library for example)? If so.. this seems like a good idea, will try it and tell you how it goes.

Comment: @WaleedMustafaAwad, yes. I'm not on Win 10, but, you probably start mongo as a service and should be able to start, stop, restart and check the status of the service. Hope it works for you.